# If/else statement in a table

Tags: r, if-statement

Let say, I have a table named `table` with headers which looks like

`A B`
`1 2`
`2 1`

What I want to do is adding a new column `table$C` such that

1. if `table$A < table$B` then `table$C <- (table$B-table$A)/table$A`
2. if `table$A > table$B` then `table$C <- (table$B-table$A)/table$B`

for each row so that the resulting table would look like

`A B C`
`1 2 1`
`2 1 -1`

I tried, quite naively,
`> table$C <- if (table$A < table$B) (table$B-table$A)/table$A else (table$B-table$A)/\table$B`
and
`> table$C <- ifelse(table$A < table$B, (table$B-table$A)/table$A, (table$B-table$A)/table$B)`
but both of them didn't work. How do I do this one?

Comment: Do you really have a backslash in front of the last `table$B`?

Comment: I removed the backslash. It's just a bad habit from using too much LaTeX. :-)

Comment: The first call assigns C twice - probably a bad idea.  The second solution looks OK to me.

Comment: Well, the second one was the correct one as Alex said. The problem turned out to be just a simple typo. :-(   RSK's answer also is quite helpful by making me to think `out of the box' since I was obsessed with if/else statement. Thanks guys!

Comment: I thought I saw a `with` answer before...that's how I would have done it. Was it deleted?

Answer (score 4):

As usual there are a *lot* of ways to accomplish this.  Assuming your rule stays the same and you never have a case of division by zero here are a few ideas...

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(2, 1))

# Making use of pmin.
df$c <- (df$B - df$A) / pmin(df$A, df$B)

# Making use of 'with' ( See ?with )
df$C <- with(df, (B - A)/pmin(A, B))

# Making use of data.table.
library(data.table, quiet = TRUE)

## data.table 1.8.2 For help type: help("data.table")

dt <- data.table(df)

dt[, `:=`(C, (B - A)/pmin(A, B))]

##    A B  C
## 1: 1 2  1
## 2: 2 1 -1
```

Comment: +1 I've noticed people using functional `:=`() recently and wondered why, though. Isn't `dt[,C:=(B-A)/min(A,b)]` slightly easier to read?

Comment: And do the `min`s need to be `pmin`s?

Comment: @MatthewDowle I'm trying to train my mind to use the `\`:=\(`` format for usage with multiple variables. :)  And, yes, min should be pmin thank you!

Comment: But `':='()` isn't needed for multiple variables is it? `DT[,c("new1","new2"):=1,with=FALSE]` adds two new columns, and `DT[,LETTERS:=2,with=FALSE]` adds 26 (unless any `LETTERS` already exist, in which case those columns are updated). Btw, there's a FR to drop needing `with=FALSE` in the first case (LHS is a `call`), but `with=FALSE` will always be needed in 2nd case (to say the column shouldn't be called `"LETTERS"`).

Comment: Well, how do you like that.  Don't know where I got the idea that I couldn't do `dt[,c('a','b'):=list(rev(A), rev(B)), with=FALSE]` but it sure enough works. Woot!

Answer (score 2):

Your second approach (without the original typo) is correct, as you note, but I think this is quicker, easier to read and less error-prone:

```
table$C <- with(table, ifelse(A < B, (B - A)/A, (B - A)/B))
```

Comment: `within` might be even better.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `table <- within(table, C <- ifelse(A < B, (B - A)/A, (B - A)/B))`? By my reckoning, it's marginally longer in this instance. Not sure about efficiency.

Comment: Oh, good point. `within` doesn't help much actually does it. On efficiency, `within` and `$C <-` copy the entire object, at least once, so I've moved over to `:=` for all tasks like this.

Comment: Yes. I'm not suggesting data.table, btw. I was just explaining why my suggestion of `within` turned out to be poor (i.e. because I'm not as familiar with it). I was just trying to suggest something that _wasn't_ data.table for a change!

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that: there seen to be plenty of data tables affcionados around here!

Answer (score 0):

Use logical indexing:

```
table$C <- (table$B-table$A)/((table$A<=table$B)*table$A+(table$A>table$B)*table$B)
```

Comment: This repeats the variable `table` 9 times in one line. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10758086/403310) for how variable name repetition can bite.